# JavaCC recognise token within token

Tags: java, token, javacc

I'm having some problem with my JavaCC project. I'm trying to recognise a variable declaration which has a possible "variable" prefix, a kind and the name of the variable (id). But the parser recognise  the first word as kind and do not go on to the rest of the line.

It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" ParseException: Encountered " <KIND> "char "" at line 2, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
<VARIABLE> ...
```

here's how my tokens are declared

```
TOKEN : 
{ 
    <START: "start"> {debugStream.println("start");} 
  | <END: "end"> {debugStream.println("end");}
  | <VARIABLE: ("variable" <KIND> <ID>) | (<KIND> <ID>)> {debugStream.println("variable decl");}
  | <KIND: "integer"|"real"|"logic"|"char"|"text"> {debugStream.println("kind");}
  | <ID: (["a"-"z","_"])+> {debugStream.println("id");}
}
```

I've also tried to put the kind and id into special_tokens, then the parser goes without errors, but don't recognise variable declaration too.

Edit:

here's the input string

```
start
    char sex
    integer num
end
```

Comment: You didn't say what the definition of `TYPE`. Also can you please show the input string.

Comment: sorry about that @TheodoreNorvell. I've edited the post to add the input string. It's a really simple one. And there's no TYPE it was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want "char sex" to tokenize as one token of kind `VARIABLE` then you need to allow spaces in `VARIABLE`s. E.g.

```
<VARIABLE: ("variable" (" ")+ <KIND> (" ")+ <ID>) | (<KIND> (" ")+ <ID>)>
```

However, I'd suggest that you consider doing the following: Change the `VARIABLE` rule to

```
<VARIABLE: "variable">
```

Write a new nonterminal

```
void variable() : {} { 
    <VARIABLE> <KIND> <ID>
|
    <KIND> <ID>
}
```